# can e.preventDefault() be reversed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, preventdefault

i am looking for a way to .preventDefault() to make a transition and then allow the default behavior

```
$('.withTrans').click(function(e){
    e.preventDeault();
    $(this).animate('opacity','0',300,function(){
           e.resumeDefault();      // does something like this exist?
    });

})
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238477/suspend-default-event-in-jquery

Comment: There is no built in function. It's also likely that the event processing is already finished when your animation ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.withTrans').click(function(event) {
    if ( $(this).data("prevented") === true ) {
        $(this).data("prevented", false);
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).animate('opacity', '0', 300, function() {
           $(this).data("prevented", true).trigger("click");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not firing the ...trigger("click") to refire the same click event.. any advice?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are trying to follow a link after the animation is complete:

```
$('.withTrans').click(function(e){
    $(this).animate('opacity','0',300,function(){
          window.location= this.href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.withTrans').each(function(e){
    $(this).unbind();
}
```

Comment: Please describe , How this answer solves the problem