# e.preventDefault - is there a way to doDefault?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Let's say I have a link:

```
<a href='http://example.com/file.zip' id='dl'>Download</a>
```

And while someone click on it, I want to do something, such as:

```
$("#dl").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dlbox").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Is there a way after I `e.preventDefault`, to go ahead and `doDefault`? something like:

```
$("#dl").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dlbox").fadeOut(500);
    e.doDefault();
});
```

so it'll run the event normally?

Comment: I asked this yesterday, maybe youi want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556107/can-e-preventdefault-be-reversed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only prevent the default behavior (with `e.preventDefault()`).

Now if you expect the link to be navigated when the [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method has finished, you should prevent the default behavior and use the callback parameter of the fadeOut method to navigate when the animation has finished:

```
$("#dl").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;
    $("#dlbox").fadeOut(500, function() {
        window.location = href;
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/gxmKW/)**

Comment: fadeOut is asynchronous, you'd have to put code into the callback method of fadeout for it to work like that

Comment: you're assuming link, what if that's a form submission?

Comment: true that :) was shooting for a general thing there

Comment: .live() has been deprecated as of 1.7, so you should use .on() or .click() instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht

Answer (score 4):

There is no doDefault() command, you need to re-architect your code.

I would prevent default, then perform the url direct yourself via `window.location`. Possibly use a different tag to an anchor tag too - by overriding its functionality it makes no sense to use it in the first place.

eg something like this:

```
$("#dl").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dlbox").fadeOut(500, function() { window.location='www.fish.com'; });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1551389/508702) can help you? You can also just return false to prevent the link to go to the location in the href.