# how to undo event.preventdefault after some time on hyperlink using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I want to my undo event.preventdefault after some time on hyperlink using jquery or javascript.
when I click on my link then it should redirect me to the link given in href after some time because i want to send some ajax request in that time

**Here is my HTML**

```
<a href="http://localhost/rightA/en/admin/vacancies/activate/181999/1" class="btn-edit-vacancy"></a>
```

**Here is my javascript**

```
$('.vacancies_tbl').on('click', '.btn-edit-vacancy', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var check = postuserWall();
    alert(check);
    setTimeout(function(){window.location = $(this).attr('href'); }, 4000);

});
```

the set timeout function is working but after some time it does not redirect me to desired link but it redirect me to this link

```
http://localhost/rightA/en/admin/vacancies/index/undefined
```

I have also tried the follwing

```
setTimeout(function(){$(this).trigger("click"); }, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){alert('sdadsa'); $(this).unbind('click') }, 5000);
```

Here is my  function postuserWall i am working on facebook javascript api

```
postuserWall(){
        var body = 'Usama New Post';

        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('Error occured');
            return false;
          } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            return true;
          }
        });
    }
```

the check show me undefined in the alert
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556107/can-e-preventdefault-be-reversed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` keyword in JavaScript confuses new and seasoned JavaScript developers alike.

The **this** Keyword

> In JavaScript, the thing called this, is the object that "owns" the
>   JavaScript code.
>
> The value of this, when used in a function, is the object that "owns"
>   the function.
>
> The value of this, when used in an object, is the object itself.
>
> The this keyword in an object constructor does not have a value. It is
>   only a substitute for the new object.
>
> The value of this will become the new object when the constructor is
>   used to create an object.

```
var href;  // globally defined

$('.vacancies_tbl').on('click', '.btn-edit-vacancy', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    var check = postuserWall();
    if(check){
       window.location = href;
    }
});
```

In your postuserWall function

```
 function postuserWall(){
        var body = 'Usama New Post';
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
          if (response) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79441/discussion-on-answer-by-jqueryking-how-to-undo-event-preventdefault-after-some-t).

Answer (score 1):

You `this` inside `setTimeout` refers to the `window` object. Instead assign a reference and use it.

```
$('.vacancies_tbl').on('click', '.btn-edit-vacancy', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this); //Assigned a reference
    postuserWall();
    setTimeout(function(){window.location = $this.attr('href'); }, 4000);

});
```

Comment: what about if i dont want to use window.location.href = hrefLink;  and want to restore the default behaviour after some time in setTimeoutfunction of the a href when postuserWall() is returned true or false